# Появление блока при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: jquery

Вот скрипт:

```
$(function() {
 $('#enterbut').onclick = function(){
 $('#enterblock').style.display = 'block';
 };
});
```

По идее при нажатии на `<a id="enterbut">ССЫЛКУ</a>` блок с `id="enterblock"` должен стать видимым, но этого не происходит (в css задано `display:none`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В jquery нет метода onclick, вместо этого нужно использовать **click** либо **on**, в jquery нет объекта *style*, стили задаются с помощью метода **css**

К тому-же - нет отмены стандартного поведения события,  в нашем случае если бы даже обработчик был бы навешан правильно - происходила-бы перезагрузка страницы, что собственно и должно происходить по умолчанию при нажатии на ссылку. И того:

```
$(function() {
   $('#enterbut').click(function( e ) {
       /*
           вместо $("selector").click( observer ) можно использовать синтаксис вида
                  $("selector").on( 'click', observer );
       */
       e.preventDefault(); // отменяем стандартное поведение

       // изменение стиля в нашем случае можно сделать так
       // этот способ быстрее всего, но применять его лучше не надо
       // хотя если сильно важна производительность - пишите так
       document.getElementByID("enterblock").style.display = 'block';

       // или так
       $("#enterblock").css("display","block");
       // или так
       $("#enterblock").show();
   });
});
```

PS: выучите хотя-бы базы jquery, это-же элементарно

Comment: И к какому блоку будет применятся display: block?

Comment: ``this`` ссылается на '#enterbut', надо бы исправить...

Comment: Действительно - не заметил, сейчас поправлю